# API URL call with PHP and cURL

Tags: php, xml, api, curl

I'm hoping someone can help me out.

I have an API call using this URL.

```
https://192.168.11.234:4444/webconsole/APIController?reqxml=<Request><Login<Username>XXXXX</Username><Password>XXXXX></Password></Login><Get><User><Username>manager</Username></User></Get></Request>
```

This works fine and returns an XML as expected.

However I'm attempting to do the same thing with PHP and cURL.

I have very little experience with cURL

So far I've tried variations of this but I get no response. only a blank page.  wondering if maybe someone could help me out.

```
<?php
$input_xml = '<Request><Login><Username>XXXX</Username><Password>XXXX</Password></Login><Get><User></User></Get></Request>';
$url = "https://192.168.11.234:4444/webconsole/APIController";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "reqxml=" . $input_xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$array_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($data)), true);

print_r('<pre>');
print_r($array_data);
print_r('</pre>');
?>
```

I will admit I have not worked with cURL much, so I may be way off.

Answer (score 1):

I love you guys(or gals) 
This works:

```
<?php
$input_xml = '<Request><Login><Username>XXXXX</Username><Password>XXXXXX</Password></Login><Get><User></User></Get></Request>';
$url = "https://192.168.11.234:4444/webconsole/APIController";
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = [ 
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"", 
    "Accept: text/xml", 
    "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_data)
]; 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url."?reqxml=" . urlencode($input_xml));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
           if (curl_error($ch)) {
           echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
            }
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        var_dump($data);
        curl_close($ch);


        $array_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($data)), true);

        print_r('<pre>');
        print_r($array_data);
        print_r('</pre>');
?>
```

Thought I was close, setting the correct headers, and changing:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

To:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url."?reqxml=" . urlencode($input_xml));
```

Is what helped. Thanks much for the help!

Comment: Turning off CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER allows man in the middle (MITM) attacks. 

If your PHP installation doesn't have an up-to-date CA root certificate bundle, download the one at the curl website and save it on your server:

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Then set a path to it in your php.ini file, e.g. on Windows:

`curl.cainfo=c:\php\cacert.pem`

[(source)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#110457)

Comment: Whose answer helped you the most, @user3294740? Please read this article ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when you try the following:

- var_dump($data);
- curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));

Edit:
Oh, and CURLOPT_POST = true

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `POSTFIEILDS` line and replace the `URL` line with this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url."?reqxml=" . urlencode($input_xml));
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

1) If your server doesn't accept POST requests then remove this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "reqxml=" . $input_xml);
```

and add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'?reqxml='.urlencode($input_xml));
```

to send data in GET request.

2) Set the correct HTTP headers:

```
$headers = [ 
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"", 
    "Accept: text/xml", 
    "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_data)
]; 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

3) To see possible errors, add these lines before line `$data = curl_exec($ch);`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

4) Also you need to add check for `simplexml_load_string`, because it returns `false` on failure:

```
if (simplexml_load_string($data) === false) {
// do something
}
```

Please let me know if my answer helped you.